# Different version of component (from what is defined in pom) being looked up during maven clean install

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a dependency and a few dependent projects.
In the pom of dependency project, I have this -

```
<properties>
<jackson-core.version>2.6.1</jackson-core.version>
        <jackson-core-asl.version>1.9.13</jackson-core-asl.version>
<jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
<jackson-databind.version>2.6.1</jackson-databind.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
            </dependency>
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>${fasterxml.version} </version>
            </dependency>
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-core-asl.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
            </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

jackson-databind.version is set to 2.6.1. After building the dependency project, when I run `clean install` on one of these dependent projects, I am getting the following errors, with version lookup failing for jackson-databind jar version 1.9.13  -

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project project-app: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.something:project-app:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE -> com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:1.9.13: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:1.9.13: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:pom:1.9.13 from/to nexus-releases-prepaid (https://project.com/repository/maven-snapshots): Failed to transfer https://project.com/repository/maven-snapshots/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/1.9.13/jackson-databind-1.9.13.pom. Error code 400, Repository version policy: SNAPSHOT does not allow version: 1.9.13 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project project-app: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.project:project-app:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE -> com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:1.9.13
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.project:project-app:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE -> com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:1.9.13
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:178)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE -> com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:1.9.13
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:279)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:1.9.13
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:247)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:pom:1.9.13 from/to nexus-releases-prepaid (https://project.com/repository/maven-snapshots): Failed to transfer https://project.com/repository/maven-snapshots/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/1.9.13/jackson-databind-1.9.13.pom. Error code 400, Repository version policy: SNAPSHOT does not allow version: 1.9.13
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:pom:1.9.13 from/to nexus-releases-prepaid (https://project.com/repository/maven-snapshots): Failed to transfer https://project.com/repository/maven-snapshots/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/1.9.13/jackson-databind-1.9.13.pom. Error code 400, Repository version policy: SNAPSHOT does not allow version: 1.9.13
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:856)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:630)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:400)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: io.takari.aether.connector.TransferException: Failed to transfer https://project.com/repository/maven-snapshots/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/1.9.13/jackson-databind-1.9.13.pom. Error code 400, Repository version policy: SNAPSHOT does not allow version: 1.9.13
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.handleResponseCode(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:372)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.access$8(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:362)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.resumableGet(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:574)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:452)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:303)
    ... 42 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

There is no 1.9.13 version defined with - jackson-databind. Version defined for jackson-databind is 2.6.1 and for jackson-mapper-asl is 1.9.13. It seems to be taking the version defined for the latter. I am not sure why it is associating this version.

Note - the repository from which the download is being attempted is defined in the settings.xml

**Update**

In the dependent project, also, which I am trying to compile, I have version specified as -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Update 2**

As per @Serg's comments, I did the following - 
 I added the exclusion against spring-boot-starter-web in both the dependency and the dependent project.
I reran clean install on both the projects as well. However, I am still seeing the attempt to download 1.9.13 even after adding the exclusions.

**Update 3**

Extract from output of mvn dependency:tree of dependency project -

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.1:compile
```

Above is followed by BUILD SUCCESS

Output of dependent project

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building project-app 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://project.com/repository/maven-snapshots/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/1.9.13/jackson-databind-1.9.13.pom
^MDownloading: https://project.com/repository/maven-snapshots/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/1.9.13/jackson-annotations-1.9.13.pom
^MDownloading: https://project.com/repository/maven-snapshots/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/1.9.13/jackson-core-1.9.13.pom
^M[WARNING] The POM for com.project:project-security:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.project:project-issuer:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.project:project-lend:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.project:project-bank:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.project:project-subscription:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.project:project-social:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.307 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-26T15:34:00+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/316M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `jackson-databind` then you don't need to import `jackson-core` as the former already includes the latter.

[image: Jackson Databind]

As you can see `jackson-databind:2.6.1` contains `jackson-core:2.9.9` while you are manually importing `jackson-core:2.6.1` and therefore get version conflict.

More generally, run `mnv dependency:tree` to see all the dependencies and look for a duplicates, specially the ones with different versions.

**EDIT**

Also as I can see from the stacktrace you use `spring-boot-starter-web` of the older versions, which also contains `jackson-databind`.

If you want to use `jackson-databind` of newer versions, than Spring provides - make the exclusion

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Otherwise, remove your duplicates and use out-of-the-box Spring solutions.

But as I can see your spring version is quite old, so I'd advise excluding jackson as in the example above.

[Available Jackson Databind versions from Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind)

**EDIT 2**

To make this all work I believe it would be enough to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The only thing I'm not sure about is `jackson-module-hibernate` as I have no practice in using it.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. It was helpful to understand, however, I am still seeing the attempt to download 1.9.13 even after adding the exclusions. I added the exclusion against spring-boot-starter-web in both the dependency and the dependent project.

Comment: I reran clean install on both the projects as well.

Comment: What is the output of `mvn dependency:tree` ? Spring Boot Starter Web might be not the only one to include jackson databind

Comment: @SandeepanNath Also remove all the `org.codehaus.jackson` dependencies -> they are moved to `com.fasterxml.jackson` and therefore deprecated

Comment: @SandeepanNath In any case - the most important for you is to identify where `jackson-databind:1.9.13` comes from and remove that.
Try using dependencies from edit 2

Comment: I found another place where 1.9.13 was defined against jackson-mapper-asl. I commented that and the issue got resolved. Thank you so much! You have been very efficient in directing me to the issue. I don't remember any such instance where it was so quick, given the complicacy!